# Numpy append vectors of same shape to different axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
import numpy as np

initial_array = np.array([[
        [0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4]],

       [[4, 5],
        [5, 6],
        [6, 7],
        [7, 8]]])
```

I have an array I want to add in:

```
to_add = np.array([
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 9, 10],
       [10, 11],
       [11, 12]])
```

Here, `initial_array` has a shape of `(2, 4, 2)` and `to_add` has a shape of `(4, 2)`. I'm looking for the final result with a shape `(3, 4, 2)`:

```
result = np.array([[
        [ 0,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [ 9, 10],
        [10, 11],
        [11, 12]]])
```

How can this be done without converting the numpy array back to a python list, is it possible to do this using numpy alone?

Comment: Add a new axis with `None/np.newaxis` and concatenate - `np.concatenate((initial_array,to_add[None]),axis=0)`.

Comment: `np.r_[initial_array,[to_add]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of ways actually, I'm showing a couple:

```
>>> result = np.insert(initial_array, initial_array.shape[0], to_add, axis=0)
# or
>>> result = np.vstack((initial_array,to_add[None,...]))
# or
>>> result = np.array([*initial_array, to_add])
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can also do that with `np.newaxis()`:

```py
np.concatenate([initial_array, to_add[np.newaxis, :]])
```

The result:

```py
Out[75]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  4]],
       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 7,  8]],
       [[ 8,  9],
        [ 9, 10],
        [10, 11],
        [11, 12]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Without reshape:

```
np.concatenate((initial_array, [to_add]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an additional axis to `to_add` so they can be directly concatenated:

```
np.concatenate([initial_array, to_add[None,:]])

array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [ 9, 10],
        [10, 11],
        [11, 12]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.append with to_add inside a list and appending only on the axis 0.

```
initial_array = np.array([[
        [0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4]],

       [[4, 5],
        [5, 6],
        [6, 7],
        [7, 8]]])

to_add = np.array([
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 9, 10],
       [10, 11],
       [11, 12]])

final = np.append(initial_array, [to_add], axis=0)
```